# \lim_{n\to ∞}c_n * a_n = 0

Tags: analysis

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in R that converge to 0 and $(c_n)$ be a bounded sequence.
Show that $$\lim_{n\to ∞}c_n * a_n = 0$$.

Obviously $\lim_{n\to ∞}c_n * a_n $ = $\lim_{n\to ∞}c_n * \lim_{n\to ∞}a_n$ = $\lim_{n\to ∞}c_n *0 = 0$. But i think this is not enough.

So I let  $ ε>0$ arbitrary. $(a_n) -> 0 $ therefore there exists an N s.t. $|a_n-0| <ε$ for all $n≥N$.

since $c_n$ is bounded there exist m,M in R s.t. $m ≤ c_n ≤ M$.

But now i really do not see how to go on.

Comment: Hint: Another way to phrase bounded is that there exists an M such that $|c_n|<M$. Now, just choose epsilon in terms of the one that you know, from $a_n\to 0$, and use this to consider the absolute value.

Comment: $|a_n−0|<ε/2$ and $M=2ε$. Then $|a_n*c_n-0|<ε$.
??

Comment: Not quite. You don't know what M is, and don't get to choose it in terms of epsilon.

You are given an epsilon, and you want to show $|a_nc_n|<\epsilon$. Things that you know are no matter what $\epsilon'$ you pick, if you go far enough, $|a_n|<\epsilon'$. Further, $|c_n|<M$. Put it together :)

Comment: So $|a_nc_n|<ϵ$ where $ϵ=ϵ′*M$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$0=\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n m \le \lim_{n\to \infty} a_nc_n \le \lim_{n\to \infty}  a_nM=0$

Comment: Provided the limit in the middle exists, which is kind of the main point of these exercises.